# NodeJS - One instance of class/module in 2 processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, instance, node-modules

I have a class in a file that exports it, as following:

**myClass.js:**

```js
class testClass {
  key = 'initial value';
  constructor(){
    return this;
  }
}

module.exports = testClass;
```

Then I have 2 node files that run separately:

```js
let instance = new require("./myClass.js");
instance.key = 'changed value';
// Keeps running
```

and

```js
let instance = new require("./myClass.js");
console.log(instance.key);
// Also keeps running
```

---

### Question

How can I make the second process print "changed value" instead of "initial value"?

Notes:

- I tried running the 2nd file after the 1st one;
- This is a very simplified example of what I need, I changed the context to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult, I think that you can not share the seme object in memory between 2 process.

Maybe you have to think about create a third process that contains the data.

For example: dnode https://github.com/substack/dnode

or use some fast memory db as Redis

---

Process 0: data store, dnode or Redis

Process 1: connect to data store and set a new value

Process 2: connect to data store and get the value

Comment: I've read a lot of questions about this, and I see redis in a lot of them, yet, I have no idea of what it is or how to use it. Can you give me something to start with?

Comment: But `dnode` seems promising, I'll take a look.

Comment: That's another large question.1. Create redis server, you can find it in [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) or [local install](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart) 2. use [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) to connecto to redis. 3. Redis have many Data types, in your example probably you need a SET: redis.set(key, newValue) and then redis.get(key)